# Error 404 Not found on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've hosted a script on locahost
on url: http://127.0.0.1/rent/

The problem is whenever I run the script it gives me "The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server."
Below is my .htaccess file:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets|install)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`

I've edited the line with following combinations:
This line: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Combinations:

```
/index.php
subdomain/index.php?
/subdomain/index.php?
subdomain/index.php
/subdomain/index.php
```

but nothing has worked, request you to please help me out here,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`?

Since your url is pointing to a subfolder, when you attempt to access http://127.0.0.1/rent, the .htaccess file inside there will use the local reference to point back to http://127.0.0.1/index.php rather than http://127.0.0.1/rent/index.php

*This is assuming you are placing the .htaccess inside the localhost/rent/ folder*

Comment: Yes I've Tried it, it gives me 500 Internal Server error.
and .htaccess is placed inside the localhost/rent/ folder

Comment: I just tried it on my side and it worked fine. Can you give a bit more information on your file structure? And what url are you trying to access? Is it just http://127.0.0.1/rent/?

Comment: This script uses CodeIgniter
/rent/main/application/config/config.php
Here I put the directory path
`*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.01/rent/';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
`

Comment: You could try to add `RewriteBase /rent/` between the `RewriteEngine On` and the `RewriteCond` which should cause it to work with /index.php. Alternatively, you can check out this [.htaccess](https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750) and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you try just the following in your htaccess?

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets|install)(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: It Gives 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: So just to confirm, both your index.php and .htaccess files are in the /rent/ folder, is that correct?

Comment: Yes they both are in the same folder